# how to match first word in each line

Tags: regex

Given the sample,

```
CODE 01 CODE 02 CODE 03
CODE 04 CODE 05
```

how to match only `CODE 01` and `CODE 04`?

`^CODE\s\d{2}` only returns `CODE 01`

whist `CODE\d{2}` returns everything :(

thanks

Comment: `^CODE\s\d{2}` works fine, or not? http://rubular.com/r/qXWJKhTXGU

Comment: no it only returns first line

Comment: What regular expression library are you using?

Comment: not sure, tested in https://regex101.com/

Comment: played in a script component in SSIS

Comment: That's because you did not select the multline parameter. See it here: https://regex101.com/r/oVHE36/1 `^CODE\s\d{2}` This is right you need to check the 'gm' options

Comment: Which actual language/tool are you using?  Presumably you're not just doing this in Regex101.

Comment: (CODE)(.*?)(01|04) this works in regex101.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `g` for global and `m` multiline option

```
/^CODE\s\d{2}/gm
```